# Copy files listed by the find command and rename it with the path

Tags: ubuntu, find, cp

I'm doing a `find` of all files with certain extension and then I copy them to a certain folder, but most of them are overwritten because they have the same name. How can I, with a Linux command, get the path of the file and replace it on the name file?

Right now I'm using this command:

```
find . -name "*.css" | xargs cp -t /folder/AllCssFiles/
```

so if I have two files on a certain path like this:

```
/something/abc/file.css
/anyting/xyz/file.css
```

when I use the command I should get something like this on the AllCssFiles folder:

```
  /something/abc/file.css   (name of the file)
  /anyting/xyz/file.css
```

Comment: elaborate your `file.css   (name of the file)` . Be more exact

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-execdir` and the command `rename`<sup>1</sup>.

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.css" -execdir rename -v "s/search/replace/" {} \;
```

if you are not sure, you can use `rename` with `-n`

```
  -n, -nono
           No action: print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename.
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>This is the syntax for `perl-rename` which is called `rename` on Debian-based systems, `prename` in some and `perl-rename` in others.</sub>